# How can I control Monaco IDE onChange event and keep it readOnly at the same time?

Tags: reactjs, ide, monaco-editor

I am using ReactJS to build a none-interactive text editor. Installed and using Monaco text Editor from this package "@monaco-editor/react".

I keep coming onto this disjunction: Either use the option readOnly, in which case I cannot control onChange events including (ctrl + z) to undo, or use the isControlledMode but then, users would be able to edit the output and we would like to guarantee its integrity.

```
<Editor
  theme="vs-dark"
  defaultLanguage={"yaml"}
  value={file}
  options={{
     readOnly,
     isControlledMode: true,
     contextmenu: false
  }}
  onChange={handleEditorChange}
/>
```

So far, the best I have come up with is a state readOnly that is flagged once the user starts interacting directly with the editor. This is the function I made:

```
const [readOnly, setReadOnly] = useState(false);
const handleEditorChange = (value, e) => {
    if (!e.isUndoing) {
      setReadOnly(true);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setReadOnly(false);
      }, 100000);
      return;
    } else {
      setFile(value);
    }

};
```

However, this case allows the user to type one letter every certain time.`